# Tell you or told you

Tags: tenses

May I know which is correct:
1. I will update you when they told me 
2. I will update you when they tell me 
3. I will update you when they have told me .

Thanks

Comment: I'd say something like: "I'll keep you updated"

Comment: As it stands, your question counts as proofreading. Please refer to the [help] for advice on how to write good answers.

Comment: @Trey Please do refrain from answering off-topic questions. We have all done it at some time or other, but it only encourages people to be lazy.

Comment: @Mick Trey has not "answered" the question. I believe he has handled it correctly, We commonly "answer" this type of "question" when we are trying to be polite. Posting a "real" answer just makes the closure issue more complicated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, "they", our subject pronoun, will be telling you sometime in the future. In the examples given:

1. "Told" - To tell is conjugated in the past tense
2. "Tell" - To tell is conjugated in the future tense
3. "Have Told" To tell is conjugated in the present perfect tense.

In this case, #2, "I will update you when they tell me", is correct. It expresses that you haven't been told yet, but you will be told in the future, and that is when the action is occurring. Also keep in mind that, usually, verbs in the same sentence are conjugated in the same mood and tense. We can see that "To update" is conjugated in the future tense, which hints that we probably have to use the future tense with "To tell" as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is too basic a question to answer here. Please refrain from answering questions that belong on ELL.